# How to split() a string with respect to multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, string, selenium, katalon-studio

Trying to extract the text **18-Aug-2019 14:00** form **Egypt Today Last Update Time: 18-Aug-2019 14:00 (GMT)** and my step was to split at ":" as first step and then do the split " (" section (basically 2 splits ), and 2 splits is not working... can we do this from only one step? thanks

Code trials:

```
lastupdated1=lastupdated.split("Last Update Time: ")[1]
lastupdated2=lastupdated1.split(" (GMT")[0]
```

The error is:

```
2019-08-19 14:54:53.692 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/REGIONAL MARKET NEWS/Verify_whether_news_getting_updated FAILED.
    Reason:
    java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 5
     (GMT
        at java_lang_String$split$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at Verify_whether_news_getting_updated.run(Verify_whether_news_getting_updated:41)
```

Comment: The error message is clear. In your regular expression `(GMT` there is an unclosed group. i.e. you have started some parentheses and not finished them. I presume you want to match a literal opening parenthesis, so you need to escape it. In java, you need to escape the escape, so use `\\(GMT` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael thanks a lot, now working fine.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: The key is that `.split` takes a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extract the text **18-Aug-2019 14:00** form **Egypt Today Last Update Time: 18-Aug-2019 14:00 (GMT)** using `split()` only once passing a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  String myNewString = "Egypt Today Last Update Time: 18-Aug-2019 14:00 (GMT)";
  String[] tokens = myNewString.split(": |\\(");
  System.out.println(tokens[1]);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  18-Aug-2019 14:00
  ```